# Second order nonlinear ODE $y''=\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ and the following trouble

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have met an ODE question related to length of curve. Let $f(x)$ be a monotone non-decreasing smooth function defined on $x\geq0$, the initial condition is $f(0)=0$. $t>0$, the length of $y=f(x)$ on $0\leq x\leq t$ is $l(t)$, there exists the equation $l(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(t)$. What is $f(x)$?

It's easy to know the length of curve is $\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\mathrm{d}x$. Do differentiation with respect to $t$ on both sides, get a second order nonlinear ODE:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}=f''(t)
\end{equation}

I tried the following:
Let $g(t)=f'(t)$, then $f''(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}g(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=g(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}g(t)}{\mathrm{d}f(t)}$, put it into above equation to get
\begin{equation}
\frac{g}{\sqrt{1+g^2}}\mathrm{d}g=\mathrm{d}f
\end{equation}

I have $\sqrt{1+g^2}=\sqrt{1+f'^2}=f+C$, but I don't know what should to do next. It is neither Clairaut nor Lagrange equation. However, when I try to use $p=f'$ and differentiate again, it becomes
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{1}{p\sqrt{1+p^2}}\mathrm{d}p=\int\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
After calculations on integral, I have $\log\left|\frac{\sqrt{p^2+1}}{p}\right|=t+C_{1}$. When $p=0$, it means $f(x)=0$. When $p\neq0$, it's feasible but too hard to solve. Is there any good method to solve this nonlinear ODE?

**EDITTED**

@Dstarred shared his solution, I calculated then confirmed this is truly a solution. But I found the original question has another restriction that $f(x)$ is a real-valued function. So Gary's comment is good but I don't know how to derive it.

Comment: Would $f(x) =\cosh (x) -1$ work?

Comment: @Gary I solved the last differential equation to get this $$f(x)=C\log\left|\frac{1+Ce^{x}}{1-Ce^{x}}\right|-C\log\left|\frac{1+C}{1-C}\right|$$

Comment: Your substitution, while appropriate, is done wrong. What you do is try to substitute $f'(t)=g(f(t))$, which then gives $f''(t)=g'(f(t))f'(t)=g'(f(t))g(f(t))$, which you then correctly used. You could also have written $\frac{f'f''}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}=f'$ which indeed integrates to $\sqrt{1+f'^2}=f+c$.

Comment: @Gary How did that assumption come from?

Comment: @CunyiNan I just solved it by inspection knowing that $\sinh^2+1= \cosh^2$ and the derivatives of the hyperbolic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of $f''(t) = \dfrac{d[g(t)]}{dt} = g(t)\dfrac{d[g(t)]}{d[f(t)]}$, why not directly treat it as a first order differential and use separation of variables.

$$g' = \sqrt{1 + g^2} \iff \dfrac{dg}{dt} = \sqrt{1 + g^2}
\\\iff \int{\dfrac{dg}{\sqrt{1 + g^2}}} = \int{dt}
\\\text{Take, } g = \tan{u}
\\\Rightarrow \int{\sec{u}\cdot du} = t + C
\\\iff \ln{(\sec{u} + \tan{u})} = t + C
\\\iff \ln{\left(g + \sqrt{1 + g^2}\right)} = t + C
\\\iff e^{t + C} = g + \sqrt{1 + g^2}$$

$$\therefore e^{-t-C} = \dfrac{1}{g + \sqrt{1 + g^2}}
\\\iff e^{-t-C} = \dfrac{g - \sqrt{1 + g^2}}{g^2 - (1 + g^2)}
\\\iff -e^{-t-C} + e^{t+C} = 2g
\\\iff f'(t) = \dfrac{1}{2}e^{t+C} - \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t-C}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the idea of letting $C=-\ln K$, but I suppose $K=i$ here.

Comment: Yes by your expression $f(t)$ should be $\frac{1}{2K}e^{t}+\frac{K}{2}e^{-t}$. Note the initial condition $f(0)=0$, then get $K=i$.

Comment: Oops my mistake, I understand. I will account in the initial condition since $K$ is not real anymore.

Comment: I must sorry for missing an important condition, that is, $f(x)$ is real-valued function.

Comment: Thats alright. With the initial condition, $C \neq -\ln{K}$. However, if we continue we have $0 = \dfrac{1}{2}e^{C} + \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-C} + K$. Then, $K = -\dfrac{1}{2}e^{C} - \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-C}$. There still needs to be another condition to solve for $C$. Since, $2$ variables require $2$ simultaneous equations. Could we consider $f'(0) = 0$ since, $l(0) = 0$?

Comment: YES, I think that's the implicit condition where lies behind the length of curve, $l(0)=f'(0)=0$ is a reasonable guess. Then by that we can have the correct answer smoothly.